# Beautiful soup returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following html code and i use beautiful soup to extract information. I want to get for example Relationship status: Relationship

```
<table class="box-content-list" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
             <tr class="first">
              <td>
                   <strong>
                    Relationship status:
                   </strong>
               Relationship
              </td>
             </tr>
             <tr class="alt">
              <td>
               <strong>
                Living:
              </strong>
               With partner
              </td>
             </tr>
```

I have created the following code:

```
xs = [x for x in soup.findAll('table', attrs = {'class':'box-content-list'})]       
    for x in xs:
        #print x
        sx = [s for s in x.findAll('tr',attrs={'class':'first'})]
        for s in sx:
            td_tabs = [td for td in s.findAll('td')]
            for td in td_tabs:
                title = td.findNext('strong')
                #print str(td)
                status = td.findNextSibling()
                print title.string
                print status
```

but the result i get is Relations status: and the print status is printing None. 
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `xs` list comprehension is a no-op; it is not needed.

Comment: @JonClements Unfortunately 3...

Answer (score 3):

There is a special method `get_text` (or `getText` in old BeautifulSoup versions) to get the content of intricated tags. With your example:

```
>>> example.td.get_text(' ', strip=True)
'Relationship status: Relationship'
```

The first parameter is the separator to use.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no need for all the list comprehensions; yours do *nothing* but copy the results, you can safely do without them.

There is *no* next sibling in your column (there is only *one* `<td>` tag), so it returns `None`. You wanted to get the `.next` attribute from the *title* (the `<strong>` tag) instead:

```
for table in soup.findAll('table', attrs = {'class':'box-content-list'}):
    for row in table.findAll('tr',attrs={'class':'first'}):
        for col in row.findAll('td'):
            title = col.strong
            status = title.nextSibling
            print title.text.strip(), status.strip()
```

which prints:

```
Relationship status: Relationship
```

for your example.