# beautiful soup find returns none from rightmove

Tags: beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am trying to use beautiful soup to parse the html from here: https://www.rightmove.co.uk/house-prices/br5/broadcroft-road.html?page=1

I have:

```
req=requests.get(url)
# page_soup = soup(req.content,'html.parser')
page_soup = soup(req.content,'lxml') 
no_results= page_soup.find('div',{'class':'section sort-bar-results'})
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'propertyCard'})
no_results, len(containers)
```

this returns `(None, 0)`

I looked at [Beautiful Soup find() returns None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529482/beautiful-soup-find-returns-none), [Beautiful Soup returns 'none'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525836/beautiful-soup-returns-none), [Beautiful soup returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968518/beautiful-soup-returns-none), [Beautiful Soup returns None on existing element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377853/beautiful-soup-returns-none-on-existing-element), but unfortunately none have helped me

The sections of the html correspond to:

[image]

and
[image]

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page indeed have a dynamic content. And you should use selenium with a webdriver to load all the content before scraping.

You can try downloading ChromeDriver executable [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). And if you paste it in the same folder as your script you can run:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# configure driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"  # IF NOT IN SAME FOLDER CHANGE THIS PATH
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

url = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/house-prices/br5/broadcroft-road.html?page=1'

driver.get(url)
page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
no_results= page_soup.find('div',{'class':'section sort-bar-results'})
containers = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'propertyCard'})
print(no_results.text)
print(len(containers), "containers")
```

You said the answers didn't help but I tried it here and it ouputs:

```
35 sold properties
25 containers
```

Comment: It never crossed my mind to use selenium. Thanks, worked a treat!

Comment: Np, it's always a pleasure to help another bioinformatician ;)

Comment: @alex check my answer below. regards.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import re
import json


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    match = json.loads(
        re.search(r'__PRELOADED_STATE__.+?({.+?})<', r.text).group(1))
    # print(match.keys())  # Full JSON DICT Keys # match.keys()
    print(match['results']['resultCount'])


main("https://www.rightmove.co.uk/house-prices/br5/broadcroft-road.html?page=1")
```

Output:

```
35
```

> You don't need to use `selenium` as it's will slow down your task. the desired `element` is presented within page source code as it's encoded within `Dynamic` `<script>` `tag`