# beautiful soup returns none from sainsbury's

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

Similar to [beautiful soup find returns none from rightmove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065662/beautiful-soup-find-returns-none-from-rightmove), but for a different site: [https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/SearchDisplayView?filters[keyword]=milk](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/SearchDisplayView?filters%5Bkeyword%5D=milk)

I try running:

```
url='https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/SearchDisplayView?filters[keyword]=banana'

# configure driver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"  # IF NOT IN SAME FOLDER CHANGE THIS PATH
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page,'html.parser')

container_tag1='pt__content'
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":container_tag1})
# print(containers)
print(len(containers))
```

[image]

to no avail.

I tried without selenium, and failed as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the page to fully render before passing the HTML to `BeautifulSoup`. One option is to use the [`.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) method from the built-in [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) module.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/gol-ui/SearchDisplayView?filters[keyword]=banana"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
sleep(5)  # <-- Wait for the page to fully render

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("div", {"class": "pt__content"}))
```

Comment: I added in a 15s sleep as well, and it still did not work for me